# NSDate get previous week, previous month issue

Tags: ios, nsdate

I need to get previous week and month from current date.

So I found solution that can recalculate current date adding interval

```
- dateByAddingTimeInterval
```

And this params for it:

`[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0]` (for getting previous week)

`[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -2629743.83]` (for getting previous month)

As I think for getting week this method works good without any problem, because each week has seven days and interval doesn't change. But for month we have a problem because each month has different number of days.

Comment: It is going to break even for weeks in regions that switch to the daylight saving time, because the week on the switchover days would be shorter/longer by one hour.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using `NSDateComponents` it would be easy and accurate

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.month = -1;
comps.day   = -1;
NSDate *date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date]; // Get necessary date components
NSLog(@"Previous month: %d",[components month]);
NSLog(@"Previous day  : %d",[components day]);
```

Comment: Does this automatically handle a year change?

Answer (score 9):

**Don't  use 903484 and -23484 for changing date**

Do this way:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

components.month=1;//next month
components.month=-1;//previous month
//similarly +1 and -1 will give you week and month day etc
components.week=1;
components.day=1;

NSDate *myMonth=[gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date]; 
NSInteger yourRequiredValue=[components day]; //day, month, week etc
```